# how to change the inner html of a div

Tags: asp.net, html, html-editor

i have a `div` and an html editor and trying to:

1. add the div inner html to the
   editor. (thats done)
2. then any changes done in the editor
   is saved back in the div.

here is the backcode :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Editor.Content = cvDiv.InnerHtml;
}

protected void preview(object sender, EventArgs e) //this is an onclick event
{
    cvDiv.InnerHtml = Editor.Content;
}
```

and the code for the editor:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />
<cc1:Editor ID="Editor" runat="server" OnContentChanged="preview"  />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="eButton" CssClass="eButton" Text="Edit" OnClick="Edit" />// this is the button that is supposed to save
```

but it doesnt work.

**so what i am trying to do is save whatever changes made in the editor to the div**

*using asp.net 3.5, and the ajax toolkit editor.*

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example i've made to show you a working code.

**ASPX**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:TextBox id="editor" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Save" runat="server" OnClick="SaveChange" Text="Save" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div id="preview" runat="server"></div>    
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="editor" EventName="TextChanged" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**ASPX.CS**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack) editor.Text = preview.InnerHtml;
        else preview.InnerHtml = editor.Text;

    }

    protected void SaveChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string thingsToSave = preview.InnerHtml;
        //Save to db/file/xml   

    }

}
```

Comment: i already retrieved the content of the div to the editor, im trying to save it back if changes have been made to it

Comment: i cant share the div because it has too many elements and lines but i can share the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using `Literal` control rather than a server side `<div />` ?

Comment: already tried a literal and a panel, they doesnt have innerhtml function

Comment: @Wahtever, With Literal, you just have to set the Text property to your html. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literalmode.aspx

Comment: i already did but it still wont work no matter what i do whatever is inside the literal or div wont recognize the changes made by the editor